# gradle: how to invoke ant.javac with multiple includes defined at runtime?

Tags: gradle, groovy, ant, javac

[for some reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451406) I don't use the java plugin for gradle, but I invoke `ant.javac`dynamically. How can I build a dynamic javac `include()` based on a list ?

for example:

```
def srcToCompile=["**/File1.java","**/File2.java","**/FileN.java"];
(...)
ant.javac(
    destdir: tmpDir,
    srcdir: srcDir
    includeantruntime:false,
    failonerror: true,
    fork: true,
    classpath : classpath1,
    debug: true
    )  {
        include(name: srcToCompile) //<< DOESN'T WORK, I also tested srcToCompile.join(":")
    }
```

thanks.

**EDIT**: by 'doesn't work', I mean `ant.javac` doesn't interpret a `List` or a colon-separated-string: no source is found and nothing is compiled. `ant.javac` expects something like

```
include(name:"**/File1.java")
include(name:"**/File2.java")
include(name:"**/FileN.java")
```

but I want to generate this list of `include` when gradle is invoked.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "does not work"

Comment: @cfrick I edited my question.

Comment: See updates in my answer

Answer (score 3):

If you look an [ant javac docs](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) you'll see that includes and include both accept a string but you are trying to pass a collection

Eg:

```
<javac destdir="${build}"
       classpath="xyz.jar"
       debug="on">
  <src path="${src}"/>
  <src path="${src2}"/>
  <include name="mypackage/p1/**"/>
  <include name="mypackage/p2/**"/>
  <exclude name="mypackage/p1/testpackage/**"/>
</javac>
```

and

```
<javac srcdir="${src}"
       destdir="${build}"
       includes="mypackage/p1/**,mypackage/p2/**"
       excludes="mypackage/p1/testpackage/**"
       classpath="xyz.jar"
       debug="on"/>
```

In Gradle this would be

```
ant.javac(includes: srcToCompile.join(','), ...)
```

or

```
ant.javac(
   ... 
) {
   srcToCompile.each {
      include(name: it) 
   } 
}
```

Comment: using a comma `include(name:"**/VcfHeadTest.java,**/VcfTailTest.java")` the sources are not compile: ` jar tvf /home/lindenb/src/jvarkit-git/dist/test.jar | grep -E '(TailTest|HeadTest)' => empty` while using `include(name:"**/VcfHeadTest.java") include(name:"**/VcfTailTest.java")` both classes are generated: ` jar tvf /home/lindenb/src/jvarkit-git/dist/test.jar | grep -E '(TailTest|HeadTest)'
  2075 Tue Feb 26 12:08:20 CET 2019 com/github/lindenb/jvarkit/tools/misc/VcfHeadTest.class
  1995 Tue Feb 26 12:08:20 CET 2019 com/github/lindenb/jvarkit/tools/misc/VcfTailTest.class
`

Comment: This would be the behavior of the ant task, unrelated to gradle